# Moving divs not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a site that has navigation links on top and when clicked, the main content div slides out and the selected content slides in and is displayed. It works fine in Safari and Chrome (Webkit), but not in Firefox or IE.  Why won't it work in those browers?

CSS:

```
#data, #data section {width:720px; height:600px;}
#data section {position:absolute; left:100%; margin-left:8px;}
#data {positon:relative; overflow:hidden;}
#data section:nth-child(1){left:0%}
#data section:nth-child(2){}
#data section:nth-child(3){}
#data section:nth-child(4){}
```

Navigation Header:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="headertop" class="headers">
            <img src="images/Autumns-header_01.png">
    </div>
    <div id="headermenu1" class="headers" data-section="one">
            <a data-section="one" href="#"><img src="images/Autumns-header_02_on.png" id="headerm1"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="headermenu2" class="headers" data-section="two">
            <a data-section="two" href="#"><img src="images/Autumns-header_03.png" id="headerm2"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="headermenu3" class="headers" data-section="three">
            <a data-section="three" href="#"><img src="images/Autumns-header_04.png" id="headerm3"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="headermenu4" class="headers" data-section="four">
            <a data-section="four" href="#"><img src="images/Autumns-header_05.png" id="headerm4"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Main content area:

```
<div id="data">
    <section id="one" class="active">
    ....
    </section>
    <section id="two">
    ....
    </section>
    <section id="three">
    ....
    </section>
    <section id="four">
    ....
    </section>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.headers').click(function () {
    var clicked = $(this).attr('id');
    var sectionId = $(this).attr("data-section");
    if (sectionId == 'one' || sectionId == 'two' || sectionId == 'three' || sectionId == 'four') {
        $('#headerm1').attr('src', 'images/Autumns-header_02.png');
        $('#headerm2').attr('src', 'images/Autumns-header_03.png');
        $('#headerm3').attr('src', 'images/Autumns-header_04.png');
        $('#headerm4').attr('src', 'images/Autumns-header_05.png');
    }
    switch (sectionId) {
        case 'one':
            $('#headerm1').attr('src', 'images/Autumns-header_02_on.png');
            break;
        case 'two':
            $('#headerm2').attr('src', 'images/Autumns-header_03_on.png');
            break;
        case 'three':
            $('#headerm3').attr('src', 'images/Autumns-header_04_on.png');
            break;
        case 'four':
            $('#headerm4').attr('src', 'images/Autumns-header_05_on.png');
            break;
        default:
            //alert(clicked);
            break;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    $toSlide = $("#data section#" + sectionId),
    $fromSlide = $('.active');
    if (!($toSlide.hasClass("active"))) {
        $fromSlide.animate({
            "left": "-100%"
        }, 500, 'linear')
        $toSlide.animate({
            "left": "0%"
        }, 500, 'linear', function () {
            $fromSlide.css("left", "100%");
            $fromSlide.removeClass("active");
            $toSlide.addClass("active");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a JsFiddle which we can test?

Comment: Is this the actual code? Wondering how this could work in other browsers if in your HTML you use an id `headermenu1` and try to change it in jQuery with `#headerm1` etc.

Comment: JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PaFmW/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be something to do with the handling of the data-section option in your HTML elements. Have you tried just opening the relevant section by means of the element index (the occurrence of the element in the corresponding list).

For example:

```
$('.headers').each(function(i){

    $(this).click(function(){

        $toSlide = $('.headers').eq(i);
        $fromSlide = $('.active');

        // rest of your code...

    })

})
```

The above code uses a 'sort-of' closure. We loop through the `.headers` elements, and assign their click behaviour based on the index of the iteration. Then, all we need to do is make sure the related HTML elements are listed in the correct order on the page.

Also, lose the `event.preventDefault()` and test.

Comment: Actually, the last part was right. the event.preventDefault() was causing it. Thanks.

Comment: @JustJon Thought it might. I was trying to shoehorn my way of handling this logic, though. It's much cleaner and less prone to syntax issues in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into the code with the closure, but it is working now.